# Thread-safe queues

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, urlsession

I am executing 20 data tasks with different URLs and filling an array with the results, but at the end of the function I still don't get the final array despite using the same queue.

```
    class func getImages(photos:[Photo]){
        var images:[UIImage?] = []        
        let arrayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imagesQueue",attributes: .concurrent)
        for i in 0...20{
            let url = EndPoints.getImage(farm: photos[i].farm, server: photos[i].server, id: photos[i].id, secret: photos[i].secret).url
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                arrayQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    images.append(image)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        arrayQueue.sync {
            print(images.count)
        }
    }
```

This function is supposed to print `21`, however it prints zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does because the *end of the function* is not the ***end*** in terms of the timeline. The `print` line at the end of the method is executed immediately before any result of the data task has been added to the queue.

You need `DispatchGroup`, the `notify` closure is executed after all tasks are completed.

```
class func getImages(photos:[Photo]) {
    var images:[UIImage] = []  // Why optional? 
    let group = DispatchGroup()     
    let arrayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imagesQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    for i in 0...20{
        let url = EndPoints.getImage(farm: photos[i].farm, server: photos[i].server, id: photos[i].id, secret: photos[i].secret).url
        group.enter()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            arrayQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                images.append(image)
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    group.notify(queue: arrayQueue) {
        print(images.count)
    }
}
```

Be aware that your code crashes reliably when an error occurs...

And your custom queue is actually redundant and you are executing 2**1** tasks

Comment: i know that there's something wrong about it otherwise i wouldn't have posted it here:), thanks for the tip.